# Elements with switched class doesn't works

Tags: jquery, class, events

I have function to switch my

```
<a class="return"/>
```

Into

```
<a class="return2"/>
```

It would allow to have 2 differents actions, but once changed, it always return the class which is executed.

Here is an example of my problem :

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Cashandrick/gztx6ztL/1/#&togetherjs=IHFlwoBnT6

As you see, impossible for the `.test2` function to work

Thank you for your help

Comment: Since you are changing the classname you need to delegate the event, at first you bind the function for those elements with that classname but after ready you change the classname but hasn't the event bind since are a "new" element: http://jsfiddle.net/gztx6ztL/2/ ... also yo have a mistake on test2 function adding and removing the same class

Comment: Thank you so much Danip ! I have been stucked and found nothing !